Why don't Active HDMI -> DisplayPort adapters work with KVMs or Docks?
There are lots of active DP -> HDMI adapters available out there that support docks and KVMs. Most of them don't even require a power-line.
However I don't see really any active HDMI -> DP adapters that will support a KVM available on the market (and what adapters are available which say they won't work with KVM are all powered via USB).
That these parts aren't sold smells like there is a technical limitation, but its nature is unclear. Can anyone help me understand why this limitation exists, and perhaps what people can do about it?
Note, this is not a request for a hardware recommendation. I just need to get my new work laptop connected to by DP KVM switch, and am looking for strategies/technologies, not specific products.

This comes down to whether an active adapter is required for HDMI to DP.
Active adapters are required when the source or input does not contain a compatible signal for the output. There are active DP-to-HDMI adapters because (regular) DP doesn't support HDMI's signal. A computer with DP++ output will not need an active adapter for the DP-to-HDMI conversion.
HDMI ports all support DP++ automatically, and so there is no need for active conversion to support the full suite of DP features.
No need for active conversion means no active adapters.

hmmm, that makes sense, and gives me a bit of hope, so I'll try out a bi-directional HDMI/DP cable tomorrow and let you know how it works out! thanks!

How is DP++ even relevant here? Aren't you talking about HDMI source -> KVM with DP in and out -> DP sink, @FrankThomas ?

Because it is within the DP feature set. If DP++ is supported, then DP is also supported. The adapter doesn't have to know what sort of thing is connected to the other end if the source port supports all possible modes at the other end, and in the case of HDMI-to-DP AND HDMI-to-DP++ the HDMI source does support all possible DP/DP++ modes.

@music2myear No idea what you are talking about (more precisely, why). If the OP are talking about a DP sink or an HDMI source (or both, obviously), DP++ is simply irrelevant. (DP++ refers to only a source port that can output either DP or TMDS.)

Besides, what he asked wasn't "why active adapter isn't necessary for some DP source to HDMI sink", but AFAICT, "why an active adapter for HDMI source to DP sink would fail to work, as per notes/warning from the adapter vendor, if the sink is 'behind' a DP KVM". (FWIW, DP KVM would mean the adapter would be between the source and the KVM, whereas HDMI KVM would mean the adapter would be between the the KVM and the sink, which is something that could matter in his concern.)

@TomYan, so its more or less HDMI source -> KVM with DP in and out -> DP sink (though actually the monitor in's are HDMI, so thats where I got the idea that an active adapter was needed, but that problem is already solved). my old laptop was DP, so I bought the KVM for that connector, but now this new laptop is hdmi out.

@FrankThomas sounds like really HDMI source -> DP KVM -> HDMI sink (and the old source is either DP or DP++). While I don't know what exactly the cause is, I feel like the warning/note your saw is probably legit, which means you probably need an HDMI KVM (regardless of whether the sink is an HDMI one). But certainly you may try "double passive", and perhaps even, "double active" first.
